# c++ lockless c-style shared array (for adding elements)

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, shared-memory

is there a known, working code to add elements to a shared, initialized c-style array (of objects) in multiple threads simultaneously without having to use lock on that resource? i mean, to a continuous memory block where elements are not linked by pointers.

i mean, algorithm, not libraries etc.
i just want to fill an array with elements in, say, 20 threads without locks or having to specify array ranges for threads where to fill (much like lockfree linked lists).

im using slackware 13.37 64 bit, pthreads, intel c++ compiler, tcmalloc allocator.

update : thanks guys for your answers, you all have been helpful with your ideas; if i could, i would mark all your ideas as answers. however, im still struggling with my code. so ill put the code up later in another thread to see whats happening exactly with my code, so people could really focus.

Comment: What platform? Or what threading library? Or what version of the C++ standard? What kind of threading are we talking about here?

Comment: I doubt it.  I cannot imagine any way that it could be done in an any safe manner.  Adding pointers to a container is not particularly easy to do in a lockless fashion, never mind anything larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I didn't get the idea correctly, but the obvious solution is just to use [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic) increment for current array index. Atomics on integral types are usually implemented as lock-free.

But if this is not true or your compiler doesn't support C++11 you could just replace it with your compiler-specific lock-free function, e.g. [`InterlockedIncrement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for VS or [`__sync_fetch_and_add`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) for GCC.

For Intel C++ Compiler [`C++ 11 atomics`](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-cc-atomics) are supported. Also you could use `_InterlockedIncrement64` from `ia64intrin.h` header file, see page 147 of [`Intel(R) C++ Intrinsics Reference`](http://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/9/4/c/8/e/18072-347603.pdf).

Sample code (proof that it works [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/ce55cf895d66a7eb420b056b6612ea58))

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

const uint max_count = 100;

std::atomic_uint count;
std::string data[max_count];

void thread_func(const char* str)
{
   while(true)
   {
      const uint index = count++;
      if(index >= max_count) break;
      // Use += to see defect if data was already initialized by other thread
      data[index] += str;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
    }
 }

 int main()
 {
    std::cout << "Atomic counter is lock-free: " << 
       (count.is_lock_free() ? "Yes!" : "No!") << std::endl;

    std::thread t1(thread_func, "Thread 1");
    std::thread t2(thread_func, "Thread 2");
    std::thread t3(thread_func, "Thread 3");

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();

    for(uint i = 0; i < max_count; ++i)
    {
       std::cout<< i << ": " << data[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can partition the array so that each thread gets a chuck. For example if you have:

```
static int array[100];
```

then each thread can work on a part of it:

```
int size = 100 / amount_of_threads;
int* partition = array + thread_id * size;
```

`thread_id` is assumed to be continuous and start from 0.

Comment: its just that index where to store an element cannot be pre-calculated.

Comment: @user1745292 I don't understand what you mean. Each partition of the array starts at 0. If you have two threads, and thread 0 writes to `partition[0]`, that results in a write to `array[0]`. However, when thread 1 executes the same code (writing to `partition[0]`, this results in a write to `array[50]`. The arithmetic used makes sure of that. You won't need to calculate any different indexes in each thread.

Comment: @user1745292 after your 20 threads has completed filling the array you can do a post-processing and "sort" the array in a way you want in a single thread

Comment: i mean, ist thread_id bount to specific memory block ? maybe i misunderstood the idea. any thread must be able to write to any memory block.

Comment: ill put it this way : is `thread 1` able to write into array[1] ?

Comment: how about redesigning this to use a global index, and threads write to a `memory block[index]`. thats what basically i am doing.

Comment: So you want each thread to be able to atomically increase `index` without using atomic increments or locking?

Comment: @user1745292 Nope, thread 1 will not be able to write to any `array` index lower than 50. For that, you will need thread synchronization.

Comment: yes, basically. i found this http://julien.benoist.name/lockfree.html to be very informative on the subject. however im still facing the problem with atomic index increase. so, maybe im using the idea wrong. thats why the topic. thats why no real code yet.

Comment: i guess this leaves me to put up code you can compile and see whats what.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to read and write the objects in the array then you can get away with just using interlocked style instructions to read and write the data. For example:

```
Foo* data[10];
// some more code
Foo *value=interlocked_read(&data[2]);

interlocked_write(&data[3], new Foo);
```

The interlocking will ensure that you atomically read a valid pointer and will take care of ensuring that you have a consistent view of memory when accessing the array. If you're using windows then take a look at the various InterlockedXXX functions in the [synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation.

If you want to read an object from the array, change it and then write it back you'll need to use a [compare and swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) approach (also known as CAS) if you want to avoid locking and also avoid the possibility of another thread changing the object your updating at the same time as you.

Comment: using CAS, is, sort of, where im heading to.

Comment: You'll only need CAS if you're planning to read, update and write back the object. If you're doing this then it makes sense to make your object immutable. This way you won't have to worry about someone reading the object from the array and using it whilst you're in the middle of calling mutator-style methods on the object.